# Parse Server Parse.User.current() returns all user data

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

My User Collection Record looks something like this:

`user: { 
        id: '123', 
        LikedProducts: 
        [{Pointer_To_Product1}, 
         {Pointer_To_Product2}, 
          .......],
         .......................
       }`

After a successful login, i call

```
const user = Parse.User.current()
```

to get current user data.

I would want "user" to contain some user fields like id, email, name etc but not everything
It also returns all product data in LikedProducts Pointers

For Instance, returned data looks like:

`user: {_id:'123', 
        session_token: '32hjn3', 
        LikedProducts: 
        [{FULL_PRODUCT_DATA1}, 
         {FULL_PRODUCT_DATA2},
         .....],
        ..............
      }`

Problem comes when there are 100's of liked products. Returned data becomes so huge that it slows down everything.

Is there anyway i can only select few fields to return in User.Current() ?

Comment: I think your best bet here is to have a second user data table that you keep variable data in for users.

Comment: Yeah, you're using the User class incorrectly. The user class itself should basically only contain login information. Sounds like another table, or several other tables, would be better for you to have to store this extra info. Attach a pointer to the User to the other tables, and you can even set a pointer permission so that those rows are only visible to the User.